# Error 'no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector' when connecting to a MySQL database in R

Tags: mysql, r

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database from R in R console.

```
library(RODBC)
library(RMySQL)
connect <- odbcConnect(MySQL(),
                       host = 'localhost', 
                       user = 'root',
                       pwd = 'password',
                       dbname = 'database')
```

I get this error:

> Error in as.character.default(<S4 object of class "MySQLDriver">) :
> no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

I have no problems accessing this database using Python and directly in MySQL Workbench (on the same laptop). My system has R version 3.4.3, MySQL version 14.14 Distribution 5.7.17, for OS X 10.11.6.

Searching Stack Overflow for the error revealed a couple of posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397850/eerror-in-r-no-method-for-coercing-this-s4-class-to-a-vector) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102956/no-method-for-coercing-this-s4-class-to-a-vector-for-utilization-of-mclust) that aren't related to my problem as far as I can tell.

Is there a simpler test or a diagnostic I could perform to make progress with my R error?

Comment: try: `require(DBI) ` which may not be necessary due to dependencies and change your connect statement to: `connect<-dbConnect(MySQL(), host='localhost', user='root', pwd='password', dbname='database')`

Comment: Thanks! I have just tried that and it now throws a different error: Failed to connect to database: Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) despite the fact I included the password and it is correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: that is an MySQL problem, you will need to resolve permissions regarding the database itself. You made need to have root privileges...is it your database or someone else's?

Comment: It is mine and I have root privileges, so when I connect using a similar code in Python I get no problems.